# Histogram for csv data

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a csv file where one of the column stands for how many followers a Twitter user has:

[image]

The csv file has about 1 000 000 rows. I'd like to create a graph showing the distribution of followers number across the whole data. Since the range of followers number is quite big (starting from 0 followers up to hundred thousands) maybe the data on the graph should be quite approximate, it can be a graph where each bar represents 1000 followers or even more (so, 1st one would be 0-1000, then 1000-2000 etc). I hope I'm making myself clear.

I've tried a simple code but it gives a weird result.

```
df = pd.read_csv(".csv", encoding='utf8', delimiter=',')

df["user.followers_count"].hist()
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Does it have anything to do with the size and a large range of my data?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bins argument in the hist function you have called. You just need to update it with a more reasonable value.

To understand: If the range is 1-10000, and you have set bins=10, then 1-1000 is one bin, 1000-2000 is another, and so on.
Increasing the number of bins (and thus reducing this range size) will help you get a smoother distribution curve and get what you are trying to achieve with this code/dataset.

Documentation link:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Answer (score -1):

Given your data , i have the following output
[image]

Comment: Yes, me too. But if I apply it to the whole dataset I have the output that I attached.

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer.